# I need a regex that will limit input to letters, numbers and a couple special chars like newline

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I'd like to limit the users input to a string that contains between 2 and 1024 letters, numbers, spaces, periods, underscores, dashes, carriage returns (new lines) and tabs.  The carriage returns and tabs do not work in my regex.  I do realize that there are other ways to check the length.

```
if (!preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9 ._-\r\t]{2,1024}$/', $userstring))
{
    echo '<p>Bad string</p>';
}
```

Thanks ahead of time.

The page has a form with the a control on it.

If I type: 1CR2 (that is 1 followed by a carriage return and then a 2), and submit the page, the error message will be displayed and the box will have 1rn2 in it.

Comment: characters that have special meaning in regexps like `.` and `-` need to be escaped with `\\` if you want to treat them as literals

Comment: What isn't working?  You may want to escape the reserved characters `.` and `-` with backslashes (`\._\-`).  Also, `\s` (`[ \t\r\n\f]`) is a good "whitespace" replacement for `\r \t`.

Comment: @MarkBaker They don't have to be escaped inside a character class.

Comment: Except for `-`, which has special meaning inside brackets.

Comment: I tried '/^[a-zA-Z0-9\.\_\-\s\t\r\n\f]{0,3072}$/' but it did not work either.  The error message gets displayed and if I type "one" and then a carriage return and then "two", I get onerntwo in the input box.

Comment: I think you need a /m to get multiline don't you?

Comment: I tried this '/^[a-zA-Z0-9\.\_\-\s\t\r\n\f\m]{2,3072}$/' but it didn't work. Thanks though.  You wrote /m.  Do I have my slashes backwards?

Comment: '/^[a-zA-Z0-9\._\-\s\t\r\n\f]{2,1024}$m/' didn't work.

Comment: `'/^[a-zA-Z0-9\._\-\s\t\r\n\f]{2,3072}$/m'` is what I meant . . . parameters after the regex string are [Pattern Modifiers](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php), that allow for things like case insensitive searches, searching across lines, greedy v. ungreedy, etc

Comment: Thank you!  Your regex works for me if I take out the $.  This works: '/^[a-zA-Z0-9\s\t\r\n\.\_\-\,]{0,3072}/m'  Now I have to figure out how to make the string that is echoed back to the screen look different.  Currently this gets displayed One.\r\nTwo.  I have not been able to figure out how to not show \r\n in the textarea and have: Two actually start on the next line in the textarea.

Comment: Essentially, when the user enters the page (data read from database), the second line is NOW properly displayed on the second line of the textarea.  If they add a third line, then after they submit it, the three lines are drawn on one with 2 sets or \r\n.  $userstring = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['userstring'])) and <textarea rows="103" cols="30" name="userstring" id="userstring" ><?php if (!empty($userstring)) echo $userstring; ?></textarea>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you're trying to match strings that may have line breaks in them, you need to enable multi-line in your regex using a [Pattern Modifier](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php).  m will enable multi-line, e.g.:

```
if (!preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9 ._-\r\t]{2,1024}/m', $userstring))
{
    echo '<p>Bad string</p>';
}
```

The `$` was also removed in case there is trailing white space.  Suggestions that others have made to use `\s` instead of `\r\t` seem reasonable to me.

Comment: Good call.  \r\n were not necessary.  '/^[a-zA-Z0-9\s\t\.\_\-\,]{0,3072}/m' worked.  But, my use of mysqli_real_escape_string is causing "\r\n" to literally be displayed in the textarea.  I need to figure out how to put them back in.

Comment: '/^[a-zA-Z0-9\s\t\.\_\-\,]{2,1024}/m' worked for me.  Thanks to everyone!

Answer (score 0):

Reserved characters (including `.` and `-`) need to be escaped with a backslash (`\`).  Try the following regex: `^[\w\s\.\-]{2,1024}$`.  `\w` matches word characters (`[a-zA-Z0-9_]`) and `\s` matches whitespace characters (`[ \t\r\n\f]`).  That leaves you with the `.` and `-` that need to be escaped.  Final PHP code:

```
if (!preg_match('/^[\w\s.\-]{2,1024}$/', $userstring))
{
    echo '<p>Bad string</p>';
}
```

More info on [shorthand classes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) and [reserved characters](http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html).

**Edit:** `.` does not need to be escaped in a character class (`[]`), thanks Barmar.

Comment: `.` doesn't need to be escaped inside brackets, only `-`.

Comment: @Barmar thanks for the heads up, you learn something new every day.

Comment: I copy pasted that regex but it didn't work. The error message gets displayed and if I type "one" and then a carriage return and then "two", I get onerntwo in the input box.  I certainly appreciate the help though.

Comment: Can you update your question with a full example?  I just tried and it worked fine for me.

Comment: Amazing.  I copied your code in, published it, and it does not work.  Frustrating.  If it wasn't for the need to allow carriage returns, I'd be home free.

Comment: Is there something before the `preg_match()` that is sanitizing your input?

Comment: $userstring = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['userstring']));

Comment: According to the docs, that function escapes `\r` and `\n`. Try validating the regex first, and then escaping.

Comment: <label for="userstring" class="label2">User input (optional):</label>

Comment: <textarea name="userstring" id="textareamessage" ><?php if (!empty($userstring)) echo stripslashes($userstring); ?></textarea><span> 1024 char limit</span><br />

Comment: How? I do know that '/^[a-zA-Z0-9 ._-]{2,1024}$/' worked.  As soon as I added \r it was game over.  Essentially this regex doesn't allow multiline which is what I need, as ernie suggested above.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9 ._\-\n\t]{2,1024}$/", $userstring))
{
      echo '<p>Bad string</p>';
}
```

I believe you'll want your regular expression wrapped in double-quotes so that your newline (you should be using `\n` instead of `\r`) and tab characters are properly interpolated.  Also, you should escape the `-` because it otherwise is used to define a range when used within brackets.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  Single or double quotes did not make a difference but I appreciate the help.   '/^[a-zA-Z0-9\s\t\r\n\._\-\,]{0,3072}/m' worked.